# Find out if system app is running

Tags: android

please explain me why I don't have Log? I want to know if Emergency dialer is opened or closed. I've tried this code but nothing happened.

```
    public class MyService2 extends Service {
    public MyService2() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for(int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++){
            if(procInfos.get(i).processName.equals("com.android.phone.EmergencyDialer.DIAL"))
            {
                Log.i("Result", "App is running - Doesn't need to reload");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And how I call Emergency dialer and my service:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.phone.EmergencyDialer.DIAL");
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(MyService.this,MyService2.class);
                startService(intent1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please additionally Override 3 functions：

```
public void onCreate()  
{  
    Log.i(TAG, "Service onCreate--->");  
    super.onCreate();  
}  

@Override   
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)  
{  
    Log.i(TAG, "Service onStart--->");  
    super.onStart(intent, startId);  
}  

@Override  
public void onDestroy()  
{  
    Log.i(TAG, "Service onDestroy--->");  
    super.onDestroy();  
}
```

Comment: For what should I do this? Explain please